# Why has Stack Overflow stopped recognising MyOpenID ID?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-accounts, myopenid

On Stack Overflow, I am https://stackoverflow.com/users/83429/plutext

However, I can no longer login as that user via MyOpenID; whenever I try to login, Stack Overflow now says:

> [The login it recognised] is new to Stack Overflow However, it is known to 1 other site in the Stack Exchange network

In my MyOpenID registration persona, I think Stack Overflow used to recognise me by the website listed in that persona.

But no matter what I try, I can't get Stack Overflow to recognise my real account (you know, the one which has my reputation, built up over time).

I can login to the MyOpenID.com site itself.

Answer (score 7):

Your OpenID on that account **is not MyOpenID**. I can't email you your *actual* OpenID, since you haven't listed an email; however... it should be familiar to you. It is a bespoke provider that you must have created (it isn't any of the usual ones, and is you-specific).

(I'm not trying to be cryptic - just security conscious)

So.... do you remember setting up an OpenID location?

Comment: Sure, via MyOpenID, I made http://jharrop.myopenid.com/ and http://plutext.myopenid.com/.  Associated with the latter I have dev.plutext.org, and it is that which I used to be able to use to login to SO. Appreciate your security consciousness, but I'm happy enough to list these, given that my password is still secret.

Comment: @Jason to count as a match, it'll need to report as `http://dev.plutext.org/projects.html` (since that is what it recorded originally). However, I can probably tweak it to something if that is no longer available.

Comment: Hi Marc, when I try to login with http://dev.plutext.org/projects.html, I am directed to the MyOpenID page, where I can choose a persona, and then when I continue, SO says "This login is new to Stack Overflow.." .. Is there particular persona details which I can set up so SO will recognise the login?  thanks.

Comment: k; unless you object, I'm just going to merge Jason and plutext (which will combine all the content and logins into one account) - that OK with you?

Comment: That would be perfect thanks Marc.

Comment: Hi Marc, Given that I can login as http://stackoverflow.com/users/1031689/jason could you please merge the existing plutext answers and reputation into that login? thanks

Comment: @Jason done and done

Comment: Great, thank you very much for that.